# cURL not returning anything for some sites

Tags: php, curl

I am executing a cURL request, and for the most part it works, but for some sites it brings back nothing, and cURL no errors. Can anybody give me some help?

Here is my little app: http://www.convurgency.com/tools/googlebot.php

Go there and enter in this site: http://www.beemak.com

As you can see alot of sites work, but selected ones dont... any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
//Bot Curl Request  


$handle = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($handle,array(
         CURLOPT_URL => $_GET['site'],
         CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)',
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
         CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
      ));

    $output = curl_exec($handle);

    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME);
    $connecttime = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME);
    $downloadtime = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD);
    $downloadsize = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);

    if(curl_errno($handle)){
        echo '<img class="errorlogo" src="http://www.convurgency.com/images/logo103.png" />';
        echo '<p style="text-align:center;">There was an error finding your site, are you sure it exists?</p>';
        echo '<p style="text-align:center;"><a href="http://www.convurgency.com/tools/googlebot.php">Back to GoogleBot View</a></p>';
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($handle);

    } else {

        echo 'No Errors';

    };

    if (curl_error($handle)) {
     print "ERROR ". curl_error($handle) ."\n<br/>";
    }


     curl_close($handle);


     $output2 = preg_replace(
        array(
         // Remove invisible content
        '@<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>@siu',
        '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siu',
        '@<script[^>]*?.*?</script>@siu',
        '@<object[^>]*?.*?</object>@siu',
        '@<embed[^>]*?.*?</embed>@siu',
        '@<applet[^>]*?.*?</applet>@siu',
        '@<noframes[^>]*?.*?</noframes>@siu',
        '@<noscript[^>]*?.*?</noscript>@siu',
        '@<noembed[^>]*?.*?</noembed>@siu',
        // Add line breaks before and after blocks
        '@</?((address)|(blockquote)|(center)|(del))@iu',
        '@</?((div)|(h[1-9])|(ins)|(isindex)|(p)|(pre))@iu',
        '@</?((dir)|(dl)|(dt)|(dd)|(li)|(menu)|(ol)|(ul))@iu',
        '@</?((table)|(th)|(td)|(caption))@iu',
        '@</?((form)|(button)|(fieldset)|(legend)|(input))@iu',
        '@</?((label)|(select)|(optgroup)|(option)|(textarea))@iu',
        '@</?((frameset)|(frame)|(iframe))@iu',
        ),
                    array(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", ), $output );

 echo preg_replace('/<(\w+) [^>]+>/', '<$1>', $output2);

 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that... fixed the code... any ideas why its not returning for some sites, but is for others?

Comment: Did you tried with a normal desktop user-agent? If works then they are filtering your request

Comment: Just tried with a normal user agent string, still didnt work, no Curl Errors

Comment: I think that @Maks3w wanted you to try it in a browser to make sure the sites actually work.

Comment: Yeah tried it in the browser, works fine. In my little app, I even have another curl request grabbing the title to the requested page, and that works fine...

Comment: Can you post the response code? it is a 200 OK ? Watch out at $httpcode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME);, it should be CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE instead of CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME

Answer (score 0):

Look at $connecttime and $downloadtime and check if the request is not timing out. Check if you can reach the website from the server where you are running the script, using command-line curl or wget.

Comment: No the request is not timing out, it is returning me the complete size of the download and the time of the download

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the target site URL doing a redirect.

By default, when curl receives a redirect after making a request, it won't make a request to the new URL. As an example of this, consider the URL http://www.facebook.com. When you make a request using to this URL, the server sends a HTTP 3XX redirect to https://www.facebook.com/. 
If you try the following you will get an empty output:

```
$ curl http://www.facebook.com
$
```

If you want cURL to follow these redirects, you should use the -L option.

```
$ curl -L http://www.facebook.com/
<full content of raw html page here>
```